# samsung galaxy ace and trying to pair my mobile with MOb-58 printer

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

I have written Bluetooth program in android it working fine. But when I am trying to run my apk in samsung galaxy ace and trying to pair my mobile with MOb-58 printer it will ask 4 to 5 times the same password for pairing.

Comment: I have same problem with Galaxy and Bixolon printer

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be in your connectivity.
You may running the code of connectivity until it gets connected. Instead of that you can make a method and put the connectivity code there. And after that just call the Outputstream to print the data.